# fusion charts x axis values issue

Tags: charts, fusioncharts

I am rendering chart using Fusion Charts free:

```
var strXML = "<graph caption='Ideation' showNames='1' decimalPrecision='0' canvasBorderThickness='0' labeldisplay='auto'>";
                strXML  += "<set name='Submitted' value='" + IdSub+  "' color='2595FF'/>";
                strXML  += "<set name='Under review' value='" + IdUndR+  "' color='FFC000'/>";
                strXML  += "<set name='Approved' value='" + IdApp+  "' color='00B050'/>";
                strXML  += "<set name='Rejected' value='" + IdRej+  "'     color='990000'/></graph>";
            
            var chart4 = new FusionCharts("FusionChartsFree/Charts/FCF_Bar2D.swf", "ChartId", "300", "200");
            chart4.setDataXML(strXML);      
            chart4.render("chartIdeation");
```

and got this chart rendered:
[image: Chart]

X-axis shows incorrect values: 0,1,1,2,2,3.
Also bars should end on the grid lines e.g: Approved

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the `decimalPrecision` set to 0. Your axis seems to be very small and you are disregarding the decimal points. So 1.1 or 2.5 is simply shown as 1 or 2.

Also upgrade to latest version.

Comment: I changed variables to start from 10 to see how it will look like and it is fine

Comment: By variable, I assume you change the data value. This may solve your current problem, but does not answer the actual issue, because you can't change data points at your will. :-)